# How to add JCalender in WebLookAndFeel

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, import, jscrollpane

I have a problem when I use `JCalender` in my project which has `WebLookAndFeel()` it shows the compile time error. Here is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JComboBox cannot be cast to javax.swing.JSpinner$DefaultEditor
    at com.alee.laf.spinner.WebSpinnerUI.updateEditorStyle(WebSpinnerUI.java:220)
    at com.alee.laf.spinner.WebSpinnerUI.replaceEditor(WebSpinnerUI.java:198)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSpinnerUI$Handler.propertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JSpinner.setEditor(Unknown Source)
    at com.toedter.calendar.JMonthChooser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at JavaProject2_25.initialize(JavaProject2_25.java:173)
    at JavaProject2_25.<init>(JavaProject2_25.java:59)
    at JavaProject2_25$1.run(JavaProject2_25.java:46)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and the source code is:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePickerImpl;
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePanelImpl;
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.UtilDateModel;
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.util.JDatePickerUtil;
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.SqlDateModel;
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.JDateComponentFactory;
import net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.impl.UtilCalendarModel;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;

public class JavaProject2_25 {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JTextField textField_5;
    private JTextField textField_6;
    private JTextField textField_7;
    private JPanel panel_1;
    private JPanel panel_2;
    private JPanel panel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JavaProject2_25 window = new JavaProject2_25();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public JavaProject2_25() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void getDataJavaProject2_25()
    {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {

        try
        {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new WebLookAndFeel());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 913, 839);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 11, 877, 94);
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        panel.setBackground(Color.decode("#35485E"));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Stock Entry");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblNewLabel_1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(380, 34, 179, 22);
        panel.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBounds(10, 135, 521, 258);
        panel_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setBounds(10, 11, 501, 46);
        panel_2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        panel_2.setBackground(Color.decode("#35485E"));
        panel_1.add(panel_2);
        panel_2.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Supplier Info");
        lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 15));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(205, 17, 98, 14);
        panel_2.add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Product Code :");
        label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        label.setBounds(30, 86, 87, 16);
        panel_1.add(label);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        textField.setColumns(10);
        textField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        textField.setBounds(125, 80, 202, 28);
        panel_1.add(textField);

        JLabel lblDate = new JLabel("Date :");
        lblDate.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblDate.setBounds(30, 130, 87, 16);
        panel_1.add(lblDate);

        JLabel lblSupplierId_1 = new JLabel("Supplier ID :");
        lblSupplierId_1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblSupplierId_1.setBounds(30, 173, 87, 16);
        panel_1.add(lblSupplierId_1);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        textField_1.setBounds(125, 167, 202, 28);
        panel_1.add(textField_1);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        textField_2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        textField_2.setBounds(125, 210, 202, 28);
        panel_1.add(textField_2);

        JLabel lblSupplierId = new JLabel("Supplier Name :");
        lblSupplierId.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblSupplierId.setBounds(30, 216, 87, 16);
        panel_1.add(lblSupplierId);

        JButton btnEnter = new JButton("Enter");
        btnEnter.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnEnter.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        btnEnter.setBackground(new Color(39, 136, 215));
        btnEnter.setBounds(371, 166, 89, 28);
        panel_1.add(btnEnter);

        JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
        dateChooser.setBounds(125, 126, 202, 20);
        panel_1.add(dateChooser);

        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_3.setLayout(null);
        panel_3.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        panel_3.setBounds(10, 407, 521, 302);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_3);

        JPanel panel_4 = new JPanel();
        panel_4.setLayout(null);
        panel_4.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        panel_4.setBackground(new Color(53, 72, 94));
        panel_4.setBounds(10, 11, 501, 46);
        panel_3.add(panel_4);

        JLabel lblProductInfo = new JLabel("Product Info");
        lblProductInfo.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblProductInfo.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 15));
        lblProductInfo.setBounds(205, 17, 98, 14);
        panel_4.add(lblProductInfo);

        JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Product Code :");
        label_2.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        label_2.setBounds(30, 86, 87, 16);
        panel_3.add(label_2);

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        textField_3.setColumns(10);
        textField_3.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        textField_3.setBounds(125, 80, 202, 28);
        panel_3.add(textField_3);

        JLabel lblProductName = new JLabel("Product Name :");
        lblProductName.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblProductName.setBounds(30, 130, 87, 16);
        panel_3.add(lblProductName);

        JLabel lblQuantity = new JLabel("Quantity :");
        lblQuantity.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblQuantity.setBounds(30, 173, 87, 16);
        panel_3.add(lblQuantity);

        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        textField_4.setColumns(10);
        textField_4.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        textField_4.setBounds(125, 167, 202, 28);
        panel_3.add(textField_4);

        textField_5 = new JTextField();
        textField_5.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        textField_5.setColumns(10);
        textField_5.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        textField_5.setBounds(125, 210, 202, 28);
        panel_3.add(textField_5);

        JLabel lblPricePerList = new JLabel("Price Per Unit :");
        lblPricePerList.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblPricePerList.setBounds(30, 216, 87, 16);
        panel_3.add(lblPricePerList);

        JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
        button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        button.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        button.setBackground(new Color(39, 136, 215));
        button.setBounds(372, 80, 89, 28);
        panel_3.add(button);

        textField_6 = new JTextField();
        textField_6.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        textField_6.setColumns(10);
        textField_6.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        textField_6.setBounds(125, 122, 202, 28);
        panel_3.add(textField_6);

        JLabel lblTotalAmount = new JLabel("Total Amount :");
        lblTotalAmount.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        lblTotalAmount.setBounds(30, 259, 87, 16);
        panel_3.add(lblTotalAmount);

        textField_7 = new JTextField();
        textField_7.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        textField_7.setColumns(10);
        textField_7.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#0080AA"), 2, true));
        textField_7.setBounds(125, 253, 202, 28);
        panel_3.add(textField_7);
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like as missing jar into package import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;, its works for me and correctly (win10 + Netbeans + Java8)

Comment: No package was installed
The problem is I have installed the oldest JCalender.jar file when I reinstall the latest JCalender.jar the problem was solved

Comment: I want to ask u something how was the project looks if any improvement had to make please give a suggestion to me.

Comment: It also getting problem if you doesn't installed the latest version of WebLafLookAndFeel.jar file with JCalender.jar file both file must be of latest version then the error was solved